# Rolling statistics for a game

Tags: python

I am very new to programming. I have only touched the surface of one language, Python, which is what I am working with at the moment. I am trying to write a program that can display random rolling numbers between a range like 1-100. For lack of being able to explain it, I would rather show a video of what I am looking to do. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88SENZe6Z3I
At about 33 seconds in you can see rolling numbers that the player must stop in order to assign it to a character trait. Less all the pretty graphics and everything, What I want to know is if it is possible to write a program that serves this same type of function in Python? If not Python, the only other 2 languages I am becoming a little familiar with are C# and Java. Would it be possible to write it with one or a combination of those? 
If it is possible, can you point me in the direction for resources to this effort. I did do a search before posting this but I found myself coming up empty for lack of knowing what to search for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “problem” is that this is not directly possible using the command line interface. If you are looking into game development you are probably going to have some graphical interface anyway, so you should look if you find a library that gives you more options in animating things.

Nevertheless, a possible solution for the command line would involve multi-threading. The reason for that is that you cannot both print (continuously changing) numbers and also wait for keyboard input. The normal command line is actually quite limited in that way.

Below you can find a possible solution with a threading approach. But again, if you are going for some game development, you should rather check out actual graphic libraries, or even game libraries that can help you.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import sys

class RollAnimation ( Thread ):
    activated = True
    number = None

    def run ( self ):
        while self.activated:
            self.number = randint( 1, 100 )
            sys.stdout.write( '\r{: >3}'.format( self.number ) )
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sleep( 0.05 )

t = RollAnimation()
t.start()

# Waiting for enter
input() # use raw_input() for Python 2.x
t.activated = False

print( 'Final roll result:', t.number )
```

Comment: I got an error when trying to run it, I posted it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XxU7J0sy). It still works though, except that you'll have to kill the Python process to terminate it. But other than that, great example.

Comment: The code is in Python 3. When you want to use it for Python 2.x, you’ll need to replace the `input()` with `raw_input()`, and remove the parentheses from the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't formulated your question correctly if people has to watch a Youtube video to understand what you want to do. Without watching the video, I can only assume you want to know how random integers work.

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 100)
```

If you want it rolling, you can simply either make three variables or display three random integers inside a for loop and place that in a while or a for loop.
Here's an example.

```
import random
import sys

try:
    rolls = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    print "Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" [rolls]"
    sys.exit(1)

for i in range(1, rolls+1):
    print "Roll "+str(i)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        print random.randint(1, 100)
```

Comment: Where exactly does that *three* come from?

Comment: @poke I assumed rolling numbers had to do something with displaying several randomized integers (like a slot machine). The purpose of my example was to show how to create random integers.

Comment: Ah okay, although having three slots from 1-100 sounds a bit weird ^^

Comment: @poke Now that you mention it, perhaps. :p I just took a look at the video and noticed how wrong my assumption was. Either way, this isn't a place to ask `how do I make a code that does this`, but rather `I've made a code that is supposed to do this, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?`. So I suppose my answer isn't all too wrong, else people can just flag it as off topic.

Comment: No, don’t get me wrong, I wasn’t saying that your answer was wrong/bad. I was just wondering about that 3 ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the graphical part of your application, you should look at pygame: http://pygame.org